# how to use gunicorn with swagger_server on flask

Tags: python, flask, swagger, gunicorn

I'm trying to start the swagger server using gunicorn on ec2 instance by using the following code:

I tried :

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -p pidfile -D swagger_server:app
```

and this:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -p pidfile -D "python3 -m swagger_server":app
```

and even this :

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -p pidfile -D __main__:app
```

How can I get it to work?

RAW python code which works : `python3 -m swagger_server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is equivalent to:

```
from swagger_server.__main__ import main
```

For this to work with **gunicorn**, try:

```
gunicorn "swagger_server.__main__:main" -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080`
```

In case you have the error:

> ImportError: No module named swagger_server

add the **PYTHONPATH** to gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn "swagger_server.__main__:main" -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --pythonpath path_to_swagger_server
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428892/how-to-deploy-flask-swagger-server-generated-from-swaggerhub-to-heroku same error but your solution not working here why ? @7311767

Answer (score 0):

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 main:app --reload
```

This should be the correct syntax, obviously make sure you're in the correct directory and source your virtualenv.

Comment: I'm getting an error  when it tries to start the server: **ImportError: No module named main**

Comment: There's a file **__main__.py** in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

isn't your application looking for a configuration file with a section like [app:main]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using flask-swagger and it has __main__.py file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
gunicorn "swagger_server.__main__:app" -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080
```