# How to deploy flask swagger server generated from swaggerhub to heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to deploy the flask swagger server generated from swaggerhub, below is my folder structure and procfile i use. Does any one knows the way to deploy this flask swagger server in heroku?

```
project
│   swagger-codegen    
│
└───swagger_server
│      │___controllers
|      |___models
│      │___swagger
|      |___test
│       __init__.py
|       __main__.py 
│       encoder.py
|       util.py
|  
│   
|_   .dockerignore
|_    .gitignore
|_    dockerfile
|_    gitpush.sh
|_    Procfile
|_    requirements.txt
|_    runtime.txt
|_    setup.py
```

content in Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:swagger_server
```

content in runtime.txt:

```
python-3.7.8
```

content in Requirments.txt:

```
connexion == 2.6.0
python_dateutil == 2.6.0
setuptools >= 21.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.0
```

content in **main**.py  file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import connexion
import os

from swagger_server import encoder


def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
    app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'end point'}, pythonic_params=True)
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=port )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error on the heroku log :
[image]

Error on the heroku web log:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but you have an unmatched ' in the the main function in the arguments dict after end point:
```arguments={'title': end point'}```

Comment: @YoavBenHaim sorry that's a typo while typing question

Comment: I think it should be `main:swagger_server` in Procfile.

Comment: @charchit tried it , again error

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorial for this, here is a article for same https://medium.com/@kar9475/python-flask-apps-using-swagger-api-deployed-on-heroku-cloud-platform-9fd2399061e

Comment: @charchit tried with same configs but resulted in wsgi module not found

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself which you can use it to deploy in appengine too, change the main content of the file as below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import connexion
from swagger_server import encoder

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'Docuware end point'}, pythonic_params=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

content in the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn swagger_server.__main__:app
```

content in requirements.txt :

```
connexion == 2.6.0
python_dateutil == 2.6.0
setuptools >= 21.0.0
gunicorn
```

this solution works for deploying in heroku, I removed the main() function and written contents without a function approach.

Comment: This helped me to deploy the same to app engine. Thanks!

Comment: @intotecho  thanks for sharing this useful info, I will add some tags  to specify that it works with app engine too :)